# Стандартная библиотека или написание собственных реализаций алгоритмов

Tags: алгоритм, java, c++

Когда выгодно отказаться от стандартных функций?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Иногда случается, что у вас какой-то специфичный случай, в котором обощённый подход, реализованный в стандартной библиотеке неэффективен. В таких случаях можно блеснуть своими знаниями и реализовать что-то самостоятельно. Однако, нужно стараться сдерживать себя от подобных выпадов. Разумеется, интересно реализовать самому какое-нибудь красно-чёрное дерево с быстрым произвольным доступом по индексу, но если если это не критично, то не стоит ввязываться.  Вы должны понять, что за код, написанный вами в серьёзном проекте приходится платить дважды, а то и трижды. Это и тестирование (многократное на каждой фазе проекта + на каждый релиз + бывают промежуточные), это и поддежка (другие люди придут и им придётся в этом разбираться и как-то поддерживать) и багфиксинг (представляете, если в вашей реализации затесается ошибочка, а вы уже ушли из проекта.. как думаете, быстро пофиксят КЧ-дерево студенты-старшекурсники? :)) )

Comment: полностью согласен. core любого языка писали настоящие профи. когда их код вам кажется неправильным вероятность того что он неправильный намного ниже чем вероятность того что вы его просто не понимате полностью...

имхо есть смысл вкручивать велосипед только с целью самообразования. в бизнес разработке это оправданно если стандартные средства вам не подходят наиболее вероятно из-за performance (пример для java - использование самописных коллекций и методов работы с ними посредством JNI)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, обычно подобным велосипедостроительством нет смысла заниматься - стандартные библиотеки/функции/алгоритмы давным-давно отработаны и доведены до хорошего состояния.

Но иногда всё же приходится - например, в условиях сильной нехватки ресурсов, когда нужно экономить очень сильно.

- Заточить функции под конкретный набор исходных данных (экономия программной памяти);
- Оптимизировать выполнение функции на конкретной платформе (экономия времени выполнения);

Ну или что-то аналогичное. Если есть возможность использовать стандартное - лучше всё-таки использовать =)

Comment: Сильная нехватка ресурсов зачастую бывает при программировании микроконтроллеров. Там же имеет смысл и использование ассемблерных вставок, как ещё один способ низкоуровневой оптимизации.

Comment: Я как раз на это и намекал =) Как пример - библиотека программной эмуляции стека USB от obdev V-USB. Вот там всего этого в изобилии =)

Answer (score 1):

От стандартных функций стоит отказаться, когда профилирование показывает, что именно они являются узким местом программы. Не надо оптимизировать раньше времени.
В качестве примера: недавно был в моей практике случай, когда очень много времени тратилось на вызов sprinf(...,"%.5lf", ...). Пришлось написать свою версию -- получился profit в 2 раза.

Answer (score 0):

Использование самописных библиотек вместо сторонних решений оправдано в некоммерческих проектах, когда пишешь продукт для души. Писать самому гораздо приятнее и зачастую проще, чем разбираться в готовых решениях. Например, гораздо проще написать цветной вывод отладочной информации в консоль и в файл, чем разбираться с настройками log4net.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен. 

Только чаще пишу не законченную библиотеку, а нужные для проекта компоненты. К коммерческим проектам это, кстати, тоже относится. Часто проще взять уже готовое свое и м.б. немного переделать, чем разбираться в чужом.